# integration_test from sdk is incompatible with firebase_storage_web

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage, dart-pub

I am facing the below error while adding firebase_storage: ^7.0.0 in my flutter web application .

Because every version of integration_test from sdk depends on crypto 3.0.0 and every version of firebase_storage_web depends on crypto ^2.1.5, integration_test from sdk is incompatible with firebase_storage_web.
And because firebase_storage >=7.0.0 depends on firebase_storage_web ^0.1.1+3, integration_test from sdk is incompatible with firebase_storage >=7.0.0.
So, because accounting_ca depends on both firebase_storage ^7.0.0 and integration_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because accounting_ca depends on both firebase_storage ^7.0.0 and integration_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)

Thanks

Comment: Could you please provide an example of your `pubspec.yaml` file? I guess it's required to have `integration_test` on your development

Answer (score 0):

Do a `Flutter upgrade`. I went from version: `3.16.9` to `3.19.3` and it fixed the problem ;)

Answer (score -2):

In pubspec.yaml remove integration_test.

Before:

```
    dev_dependencies:
     flutter_test:
      sdk: flutter
     integration_test:
      sdk: flutter
```

After:

```
    dev_dependencies:
     flutter_test:
      sdk: flutter
```

It should help.

Comment: I have removed the version number from some of the dependencies in yaml file and it worked ..